# Increment issue while creating a unique order number

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating order numbers like this:

```
    ACC4_11082018_1    

    ACC4_11082018_2

    ACC4_11082018_3

    ACC4_11082018_4

    ACC4_11082018_5
    .
    .
    .
    .
    etc.
```

I am getting an issue with incrementing the last digit.
I tried the code

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$myDate = date('dmY');
$get_id=4;
$i=1;
echo $order_no='ACC'.$get_id.'_'.$myDate.'_'.$i;
$i++;
```

Would you help me out with this?

Comment: You must re-create the string after incrementing `$i`. It won't update the previous string.

Comment: @Qirel, Yes it's not updating the previous one. I know, I have to use some for or while condition but I am still confuse

Comment: What is the logic here? Where does those numbers came from?

Comment: Well, why don't you read the last order id placed on the day (if it exists) from the database and increment from that one? This way you really only need to insert the first row for the day.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte, My logic is, ACC is the string which I added manually, 4 is the customer id. then current date and last digits is the number which start from 1 to infinity.

Comment: Why do your desired examples start with `ACC` but your code starts with `v`. Wild good chases are not appreciated around here...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, Oh!  My bad, while paste the code.

Comment: Please change 'no' to 'number' where needed for clarity.

Comment: @GrahamAsher, What more clarity you need? Please let me know I will explain you in a details

Comment: I have edited it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue where you will be using this code/logic but this will give you infinity:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$myDate = date('dmY');
$get_id=4;

$i=0;

while( ++$i )
{
    echo $order_no='ACC'.$get_id.'_'.$myDate.'_'.$i;

    // echo '<br>'; // uncomment this if you want it to look normal in your browser
}
```

Or if infinity is not desired then:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$myDate = date('dmY');
$get_id=4;

$i=0;

// stop after 1,000
while( ++$i <= 1000 )
{
    echo $order_no='ACC'.$get_id.'_'.$myDate.'_'.$i;

    // echo '<br>'; // uncomment this if you want it to look normal in your browser
}
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, I don't want to stop the order no because order no is unique for each buyer. once user buy the product the order no will generate unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to generate a unique order number for anything:
you have to check that order number if already exists in database or note

```
/* --------------------------- New order number --------------------------- */

    $check_for_order = $con->query("SELECT `order_no` FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
    if($check_for_order->num_rows==1){

    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($check_for_order);
    $previous_order = trim($row['order_no']);

    $new_order = $previous_order + 1;

    $insert_order_number = $con->query("INSERT INTO `table`(`order_no`) VALUES ('{$new_order}')");

    }else{

    $previous_order = 1;

    $on_date = date("Ymdhis"); // or you can use time() instead

    $new_order = $on_date.$previous_order;

    $insert_order_number = $con->query("INSERT INTO `table`(`order_no`) VALUES ('{$new_order}')");
    }

    /* ----------------------- New Order Number here -------------------------- */

    $order_no = $new_order;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Your answer is not bad, but I don't want to do this because I need a quick and fast reply that's the reason I need a unique number. So it will always run and generate a unique number with no limit.

Comment: You can use time()  And/or Uniqid() It will be unique